# Android Java: countdowntimer starts in one activity and finishes in another one. Is it ok?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make something like a timed session when a user logs in in the app. I want to set up a timer which, when finished, change the activity with an intent, going back to the login page. I'm new to Android programming and I don't know how something like this should be implemented.
What I tried so far (and currently is working as intended, I just don't know if it's the correct thing to do, because it seems odd to have a function from another activity running in the background like this) is:

- Countdowntimer is setted up in the login activity.
- When the "login" button is pressed the timer starts.
- OnTick() changes the activity with an intent.
- OnFinish() is setted up in the login activity and, when it runs, it changes activity with an intent going back to the login page, even if the user is on a completely different activity.

As I said before, this works just fine, it just seems strange and I can't find anything that tells how this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Using Intent Service Start your Timer & Add Event Bus Dependency to your project.
[Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#add-eventbus-to-your-project)

```
public class TimerIntentService extends IntentService {

public TimerIntentService() {
    super("TimerIntentService");
}

public static void startTimer(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimerIntentService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
}

private CountDownTimer countdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000,1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEventToActivityEvent(TimerStatus.RUNNING));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEventToActivityEvent(TimerStatus.FINISHED));

    }
};

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEventToActivityEvent(TimerStatus.STARTED));

    countdownTimer.start();

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try{
        countdownTimer.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    stopSelf();
}}
```

step 2:
in your first activity start intent service

```
TimerIntentService.startTimer(context);
```

step 3:
in your base activity or second activity add like the following

```
public class TimerBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN,sticky=true)
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEventToActivity event) {

    if(event.timerStatus!=null){
        if(event.timerStatus==TimerStatus.FINISHED){

            // do your Stuff

        }

        if(event.timerStatus.equals(TimerStatus.RUNNING)){
            Log.e("Timer State : ",""+event.timerStatus.name());
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this code but it just gave me a bunch of errors. After modifying it a bit I don't have errors anymore, but it doesn't work. The application works just fine but the timer is never activated. (I don't get what you mean with "TimerStatus.RUNNING", what is it? I had to replace it with a boolean variable in order to not get any errors)

Answer (score 0):

With Koin DI & MVVM It is a very simple one.

Step 1: define your timer in your ViewModel

```
class TimerViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {


val isFinished = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = false }

val timerTask: CountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

    override fun onFinish() {
        Log.e("CountDownTimer","onFinish")
        isFinished.postValue(true)
    }

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        Log.e("millisUntilFinished","$millisUntilFinished")
    }

}}
```

step 2: Add your model as a singleton using Koin

```
val myModule = module {
single { TimerViewModel(androidApplication()) }}
```

Step 3: start your time in Your first activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    val timerViewModel: TimerViewModel by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        activityMainBinding.viewModel = timerViewModel
        activityMainBinding.lifecycleOwner = this

        timerViewModel.timerTask.start()

        startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))

    }
```

Step 4: Observe ViewModeldata in Second Activity

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val timerViewModel: TimerViewModel by inject()

    lateinit var activitySecondBinding: ActivitySecondBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activitySecondBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_second)
        activitySecondBinding.viewModel = timerViewModel
        activitySecondBinding.lifecycleOwner = this

        timerViewModel.isFinished.observe(this, Observer {isTimerFinished->
            if(isTimerFinished){
                Toast.makeText(this@SecondActivity,"Timer Finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })

    }

    fun stopTimer(view:View){
        timerViewModel.timerTask.cancel()
    }


}
```

Note:
Problem Solved. This is one of the ways. If you don't want to use singleton object, then run your timer in IntentService. onFinish notify to the activity using EventBus. Event Bus will share your event with multiple activities.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using Kotlin, the app is basically finished, it only needs this timer and I don't have time to rewrite everything. I'm trying to use the IntentService solution you provided, but I'm finding it hard to implement. Any advice?